# android runtime error vibration

Tags: android, runtime-error, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

[image]
have only 2 vibration calls in my app

```
1. Vibration Call 

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                        int position, long id) {
...
    vibrator.vibrate(200);
...}
}

2. Vibration Call    

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
    }
    ....
//z axes accelerator changes
    long[] pattern = { 0, 200, 200 };
                    vibrator.vibrate(pattern, 3);
    }}
```

I think first one is coasing the error.

I really do not see any error.

Its my first time programming vibration.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For now best solution is

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
vibrator.vibrate(200);
        }

});
}
```

App does not crash but vibration sometimes fails

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work

```
long[] pattern = new long[]{ 0, 200, 200 };
                    vibrator.vibrate(pattern, 3);
```

Comment: vibrator.vibrate(pattern, 3); means repeat pattern 3x

Comment: @nkvnkv edit my answer i think you forget to initialise array